# Accessing ASP.NET MVC routing parameters in AngularJS $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, angular-routing, ngroute

I'm a newbie working with AngularJs routing in Asp.net mvc. I've read quite a lot of articles on internet already and might still have a little confusion when it comes to routing.

My problem is, i have multiple MVC controllers take these two for example Reviews and Broker.

In _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("See Review", "Index", "Reviews", new { reviewId = 1299 }, null)
```

My Index action on Reviews controller takes the reviewId. My URL right now takes the form as:

```
http://localhost:52881/Reviews/Index?reviewId=1299
```

I want to get this reviewId in my angular controller therefore i have declared my route as:

```
var reviewModule = angular.module('reviewModule')
reviewModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
var basePath = 'App/views/partial/';
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/reviews'
    }).
    when('/reviews', {
        templateUrl: basePath + 'review/review.html',
        controller: 'reviewscontroller'
    });
```

});

Now when i run the application and click on See Review link, my url becomes

```
http://localhost:52881/Reviews/Index?reviewId=1299#/reviews/
```

That's probably because angular routing engine took the url after the mvc querystring has ended and called the redirectTo '/reviews'.

In my reviewscontroller.js when i try to get the reviewId, i get an undefined probably because nothing was transferred after the #/reviews/ to angular route. Here is how i am getting the parameter in reviewscontroller.js controller.

```
console.log($routeParams.listingNumber);
```

My question is, how asp.net mvc action parameters can become the part of the angular route so that they can later be accessed for further processing?